# Subsonic 3.0 select Query using DateColumn

Tags: c#, subsonic3

While selecting records using Date-Field i am facing a problem ,

my SQL2005 View (ViewOrders) StarDate column Have

```
4/23/2010 12:00:00 AM
4/23/2010 12:00:00 AM
4/23/2010 12:00:00 AM
4/23/2010 12:00:00 AM
4/23/2010 1:07:00 PM
```

My Code using subsonic 3.0

```
AMDB ctx = new AMDB();
SqlQuery vwOrd = ctx.Select.From<viewOrders>();   
vwOrd = vwOrd.And("StartDate").IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo("04/22/2010");//From date
vwOrd = vwOrd.And("StartDate").IsLessThanOrEqualTo("04/22/2010");// To Date
List<viewOrders> cat = vwOrd.ToList<viewOrders>();
```

i can able to fetch only first four records, i can't able to fetch the final record which start date contains(4/23/2010 1:07:00 PM). 
I think the problem is in the time format..

How can i code in subsonic ,which compare only the date in the date-time column.

I Don't need date "Between" method in subsonic, since i can get single date parameter(From date alone).

Comment: my SQL2005 View (ViewOrders) StarDate column Have

(R1)4/23/2010 12:00:00 AM 
(R2)4/23/2010 12:00:00 AM 
(R3)4/23/2010 12:00:00 AM 
(R4)4/23/2010 12:00:00 AM 
(r5)4/23/2010 1:07:00 PM

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, getting datetime records within a date range is normally achieved by (psuedo code)

```
DateField >= startdate AND DateField < (EndDate + 1 day)
```

I'm slightly confused by your example where your date records are all 23-Apr-10, but you seem to be searching for those on 22-Apr-10?

Also, as a general bit of advice, do date comparisons using the format 'YYYYMMDD' - this will cope with different servers in different date formats.